# C# recursive loop

Tags: java, c#, recursion

I have these data

```
string [] letters = {"a","b","c"};
```

I want a function like, generateString(1)
if value is 1, then output is:

```
a
b
c
```

if generateString(3), the output is

```
a
b
c
aa
ab
ac
ba
bb
bc
ca
cb
cc
aaa
aab
aac
aba
abb
abc
aca and so on...
```

i can do it like this,

```
foreach(var a in data){
 foreach(var b in data){
  foreach(var c in data){
    Console.WriteLine(a + b + c);
  }
 }
}
```

it can only generate upto 3, if i want to make it 4, then i add another foreach, which is i think not a better idea.

any suggestions?

Comment: If you did recursion, what would it look like? Have you tried something?

Comment: You might try researching what recursion is before you attemp.. ask someone else to attempt it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
static string[] generateString(string[] letters, int len)
{
    if (len < 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("length can't be less than zero.");
    switch (len)
    {
        case 0: return new string[0];
        case 1: return letters;
        default:
            // all possible combinations which are shorter than required 
            // recursion is used here
            var shorter_x = generateString(letters, len - 1).ToArray();

            // all combinations which have length = len - 1
            var shorter_1 = shorter_x.Where(line => line.Length == len - 1).ToArray();

            // resulting array
            return shorter_x.Union(letters.SelectMany(letter => shorter_1.Select(shorter => letter + shorter))).ToArray();
    }
}
```

**UPD:** representing data as

```
char[] letters = { 'a', 'b', 'c' }
```

would be more consistent. In this case the function will look like

```
static string[] generateString(char[] letters, int len)
{
    if (len < 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("length can't be less than zero.");
    switch (len)
    {
        case 0: return new string[0];
        case 1: return letters.Select(char.ToString).ToArray();
        default:
            ......
```

Comment: It really works! but I wanted to use every single string that has been generated. If I'm gonna use generateString(20), my computer crashes because it cannot handle that big data storing to one variable.

Comment: You can try to use nonrecursive version. And lazy iterator

Answer (score 0):

It will look someting like this

```
List<List<String>> foo(int i){
    if(i==1){
        return new List<List<String>>(new List<String>("a", "b", "c"));
    } else{
        var result = new List<List<String>>();
        foreach(List<String> list in foo(i-1)){
            foreach(String elem in new String[]{"a", "b", "c"}){
               var tmp = new List<String>(list);
               tmp.Add(elem);
               result.Add(tmp);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure about sintax and list constructor but in general idea is shown